# Does querydsl for mongodb support $text (full text) search ? (using querydsl with spring data mongodb)

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I am using querydsl to construct dynamic search queries (and using spring data mongodb API to execute it). Is there a way to construct querydsl query with support for $text (full text) search ?

Comment: Looking for the same.. no luck so far :/

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but in case anyone stumbles across it in the future, I was able to encapsulate MongoDB full text search in a Querydsl `Predicate` as follows:

```
import com.querydsl.core.types.ExpressionUtils;
import com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.Expressions;

public static Predicate toTextPredicate(final TextCriteria criteria) {
    final var path = ExpressionUtils.path(Document.class, "$text");
    final var value = Expressions.constant(criteria.getCriteriaObject().get("$text"));
    return ExpressionUtils.predicate(Ops.EQ, path, value);
}
```

Once you have a `Predicate`, you can combine it with any other search term via `BooleanBuilder` and so forth. Assembling the Spring Data MongoDB `TextCriteria` is left as an exercise for the reader. It is well documented elsewhere.

You could do the same without Spring Data MongoDB by constructing the MongoDB `$text` constraint document manually.

This is a little sneaky in the way it tacks on the `$text` constraint through the `Ops.EQ` block in `MongodbDocumentSerializer`, but it works "well enough" in the absence of first class support in Querydsl itself.